# Kernel of product

Tags: matrices

Let $B \in \mathbb R^{{k}\times {m}}$ and $A \in \mathbb R^{{m}\times {n}}$. Further assume that $\operatorname{ker}(B) \cap \operatorname{ran}(A) = \{0\}.$ Show that this implies $\operatorname{ker}(A) = \operatorname{ker}(BA).$

I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: What is Ran(A)?

Comment: Suppose $BAx=0$. What can you say about the vector $Ax$ in terms of $\mathrm{Ran}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(B)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard, but the structure is a bit verbose, hope that helps.
$$\text{Ker}(A)=\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n ~|~Av=0\}$$
$$\text{Ker}(BA)=\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n ~|~BAv=0\}$$
If $v\in\text{Ker}(A)\Rightarrow Av=0 \Rightarrow BAv=0\Rightarrow v\in\text{Ker}(BA)$

or if $Av=u\neq0\Rightarrow (u\in\text{Ran}(A)$ and $B(Av)=0 \iff Bu=0)$, thus:
$$\text{Ker}(BA)= \text{Ker}(A) \cup \{v\in \mathbb{R}^n/\text{Ker}(A)~|~u=Av~\text{and}~u\in\text{Ker}(B) \}$$
But, $\text{Ker}(B)\cap\text{Ran}(A)=\{0\} \Rightarrow (u\in\text{Ran}(A)/\{0\}\Rightarrow u\notin\text{Ker}(B))$

If $v\in \mathbb{R}^n/\text{Ker}(A) \Rightarrow  Av\in\text{Ran}(A)/\{0\}$, thus (from above) $u\notin \text{Ker}(B)$, so no element of $v\in \mathbb{R}^n/\text{Ker}(A)$ satisfies $u\in \text{Ker}(B)$ and $\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n/\text{Ker}(A)~|~u=Av~\text{and}~u\in\text{Ker}(B) \}=\{\}$, finally:
$$\text{Ker}(BA)= \text{Ker}(A) \cup \{\} = \text{Ker}(A)$$

Comment: $0$ is always an element of the kernel of a matrix. You should consider $v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ in your definition, not $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: You are right @Eric, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

$\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(BA)$ is obvious.

Suppose $v\in\ker(BA)$. Then $B(Av)=0$, so $Av\in\ker(B)\cap\operatorname{ran}(A)$. Hence $Av=0$, so $v\in\ker(A)$.